# how to prevent/ secure delete request method from any attacker in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CategoryDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Category
template_name = 'board/delete.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('category-list')

path('category/<int:pk>/delete', CategoryDeleteView.as_view(),name='category-delete')
```

if a attacker runs the script from logged in user browser with random category id, how we will prevent from this kind of attacks in Django or Django rest framework

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do in DRF, is specify a queryset of the allowed objects for the user.
That way when trying to retrieve/delete an object that doesn't belong to him, he'll get a 404 not found response.
For example:

```
class CategoryDeleteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Same thing goes for normal Django views (specify a pre-filtered queryset, and only let the user query that).